# "Invalid 32-bit application" error when running "import Leap"

Tags: python-2.7, leap-motion

I'm trying to use the Leap Motion SDK with Python. I put all the required files in the appropriate locations but when I run this:

```
>>> import Leap
```

I get an error:

> Invalid 32-bit application

I'm on 64-bit Windows 7 running a 64-bit Python 2.7.5. The rest of my software is also 64-bit. What could be the problem, and how can I fix it?

## Update

Adding the Leap Motion SDK library to the `PATH` environment variable fixes this.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't think there's enough information here to diagnose your problem. Please describe what you were trying to do, how you tried to do it, and what specifically has not worked with that approach.

Comment: thanks icktoofay, I have just started leap motion sdk on python. and trying to run import Leap throws a invalid 32 bit error eventhough my python, windows, all Leap motion dlls and pyd files are 64 bit.

Comment: Since you appear to have found the solution, you may want to post the solution as an answer on your question rather than just editing it into the question. That way you can get credit for it if other people find your solution helpful.